# How to call a parameterized constructor using a array type object in C++

Tags: c++, oop, object, constructor

I have created a class named 'employee' , and i want the object of the class to invoke the parameterized constructor `employee::employee(char* name, int id)` when they are created,and the objects were declared as array of objects `employee emp[]`, the following code represent so.
I tried using the following syntax:

`for(int x=0; x<10; x++)  //say for 10 objects of employee class
{   cin>>l>>b>>h;
    employee emp[x]={employee(l,b,h)};  //i don't whether its correct or not
}`

but this code is giving the following error:

**//error: line 29: Constant expression required**

Following is the code which I compiled:

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
class employee
{
char* name;
int eid;
public:
employee()
{ }
employee(char* name, int eid)
  {
    this->name=name;
    this->eid=eid;
  }
void display()
  {
    cout<<name<<" "<<eid<<"\n";
  }
};
int main()
{       char *name;
    int id;
cout<<"ENTER NAME AND EID OF 10 EMPLOYEES:";
for(int x=0; x<10; x++)
{       cout<<"enter name:\n" ;
    cin>>name;
    cout<<"enter id:\n";
    cin>>id;
    employee emp[x]={employee(name,id)};  //line 29
}
return 0;
```

}

Comment: You should read about C++ basics first...

Comment: Given that `x` is changing on each iteration of the loop and you have `employee emp[x] = ...` inside this loop, what do you think this is doing?

Comment: sorry, still a beginner, I was not able to find it anywhere,

each object emp[x], when the value of x changes becomes a completely new object of the class employee, so I tried to access the data member with each new object

Comment: is it not possible ?